# Do HTTP requests between two applications hosted on the same IIS instance go through the network?

Tags: iis, networking, https

We have many Web API installed on the same VM. They receive requests from other VM but they also communicate with each others.

I wonder how HTTP requests made between two APIs installed on the same IIS instance are handled.

Does IIS pass the request to the second API directly, without going through the network or is the request sent over the network?

The reason why I ask: I'm wondering if I should use HTTPS for these intra-VM calls. If the data is not visible on the network, it's probably safe to use HTTP.

Thanks.

EDIT --

Example of an HTTP call done from WebAPI W1 to WebAPI W2, both installed on the same IIS instance: `http://w2/getversion`.

Comment: If you don’t show us more details like how the actual requests are sent (exact URL for example), no further discussion can be made. Note that even on the same machine packets can be sniffed, so HTTPS is always better for privacy and you should use it.

Comment: as lex li said in any situation it is recommended to use https for the privacy perspective. and apart from that if you are using public ip or the url with you api to communicate it will go through network

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks for the advice. All the VM are on a private network. We were asked to switch to HTTPS. Since this involve some work and since we're kind of busy :), I was thinking to do this in 2 steps: switch to HTTPS for all calls between VM now, do the same for intra-VM calls later.